# widgets doesn't show up in android 4.1 and 4.2

Tags: android, android-widget

I created an app with widget, When  test my app in emulator with android 2.2 everything works fine, but in my galaxy s device with android 4.2 my widgets doesn't shown in widgets area!!
 Whats the problem?

Comment: You made an error. If you want a more detailed answer, you really need to provide more details!

Comment: i say, how can this happen? in emulator my widgets loads correctly but in android 4+ in real device not... give me some possible reasons. please

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

Step #1: Add an activity to your app.

Step #2: Launch that activity from the home screen launcher.

Step #3: Then go look for your app widget.

`BroadcastReceivers` are disabled on Android 3.1+ until a component (e.g., an activity) has been directly invoked (e.g., run from the launcher). `AppWidgetProvider` extends `BroadcastReceiver`. Depending upon the home screen implementation, this may mean that your app widget will not appear in the list of app widgets until a a component has been directly invoked.

Comment: i have a lot of activities in my project. my app work finely but only widgets not...

Comment: @FarhadShirzad: Then I do not have an explanation for the behavior that you are seeing. If you somehow create a sample project that reproduces the behavior (app widgets work on earlier versions but not on Android 4.x, even after launching an activity), post it somewhere, and I'll try to take a peek at it.